# Ignoring maturity, which database would be better for storing spatial data?

Tags: postgresql, mongodb, geolocation, postgis

I am looking to store possibly millions of spatial locations.  I will need to do queries like "hotels within 10 miles of [lat,lng]".

I've had a little experience with MongoDB in this regard and was actually impressed at how easy it was.  However, I'm thinking long-term and am wondering how well MongoDB would perform with giant queries like this vs Postgres/GIS.

I know maturity is a factor but it seems like most people say go with Postgres/GIS because it's mature.  But is that really the best reason?

What are your thoughts?  Any other alternatives like MySQL?  SQL Server?

Comment: too localized??

Comment: how is this too localized?

Comment: yeah, too localized? wtf?